# why when i click like button on my website, it always shows confirm button?

Tags: html

it's ok on my computer but when i posted it online, after clicked like it always shows up a confirm button.
here is my like button code:

```
 <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?  app_id=231169313564386&href=http%3A%2F%2F{4}&layout=button_count&width=450&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

here is picture:[image: like button]

[image: after clicked like]

[image]

Comment: Facebook shows you the confirm button?

Comment: What kind of button with what message exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is facebook's security to stop you "hacking" an account

Comment: but i checked on other sites and their all works fine and how can i turn it off?